# How to implement a permissions system that varies according to the values a user is attempting to save?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, user-permissions

The context is a educational administration system built on the Zend Framework. We are implementing a RESTful MVC to handle pretty much all data interactions with clients. Relationships between resources are mapped in the database with foreign keys etc.

Example case: a teacher creating a report on a specific student.

We currently have a role-based permissions system that can be tailored to the level of the individual role (using, eg, `teacher_5` as the role name). Therefore we can easily restrict access to an already existing report (by generating permissions in the report model that allows edit/put permissions on the report only to the tutor role who created it, say). The problem comes on creation. In order to add a report a user can post to /reports, say, the following data:

```
{ achievement: "4", performance: "5", student_id: "10" }
```

The problem is that tutors are only allowed to create new reports on a certain subset of `student_ids` - those students that they are teaching.

One approach would be to treat this as a validation issue on that field. The issue with this is that we want to protect ourselves from making mistakes, and that is not easy to do with validation (the code would have to know in advance that special validation is expected on certain fields).

The other would be to somehow extend our permissions system to a completely granular one (i.e., there would be a permission for every field in every model), and then extend our current permissions system to responding to paramaterised permissions checks. So if we wanted to know if the current user has permissions to add student_id 10 to a report on creation, we would end up with something like

```
if ($acl->isAllowed($resource, $role, $action, $field, $value))
```

where $resource would be a report model, $role would be the teacher `teacher_5`, `$action` would be "post", $field would be `student_id`, and $value would be 10. The acl class would essentially handle a call to the `$resource` itself.

We are not sure which direction to take, but presumably this is a fairly common issue, so we are wondering what approach other people have taken.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Zend ACL Assertions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html#zend.acl.advanced.assertions) yet?  I use those in situations like yours where there is more complex logic involved in granting/denying access.  That may be what you are looking for.

Comment: drew010: That's what I'd use ;)

Comment: Thanks @drew010. I did look at that a while ago... I think I dismissed it because I'm currently using the default resource object. Would the idea be that I made my models implement Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface, and then in the assertion itself I would pull the relevant details out of the model and implement the logic there? 

Also, assertions only apply if they return true, so I would have to add separate deny and allow rules for each action. But in that case, which one takes precedence?

Comment: Having said that, I suppose the assertion rule could simply proxy to an isAllowed method on the model, and the allow rule would return isAllowed, while the deny rule returned !isAllowed and then there could be no confusion.

Comment: @kasimir It may be a bit tricky to work out for your given case, but I've used assertions to do some interesting things.  You can use assertions even without a defined role or resource as they demonstrate with the `CleanIP_Assertion` on the ZF manual.  I am not 100% sure, but I believe the assertion is only tested if the role can access the requested resource and privilege so if none of those are true, there is no need to test the assertion.  Basically, I've used an assertion to look even deeper into the logged in user (regardless of role) and used the assertion to decide if the user can

Comment: ...access the requested feature.  It may not work in your case, but I figured not having to have a secondary layer of logic/control that you had to query in addition to the ACL would be good.  But hopefully you can get creative with the assertions and find a way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: A solution along these lines is possible in my case only by slightly modifying Zend_ACL to allow assertions to allow or deny, rather than being rules for implementing an allow or deny. However, there were very serious performance issues with this method, and we are going to go down a different road involving defining higher level abstractions that represent the properties of a resource that are of ACL interest and then implementing a cache - for details please PM me.

Comment: I assume that the association between student and teacher is defined someplace else, so you could (1) instantiate a dynamic assertion object, injecting the relevant mapper/data-access object (2) implement the `assert()` method on the dynamic dynamic assertion object, using the mapper to check the student/teacher association (3) Check `$acl->isAllowed()` in the controller. Doesn't seem overly performance-intensive since the check will only be performed when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

What about having another table containing the student_id's that each teacher tutors. Then you can easily check if the teacher is allowed to do the insertion. Another benefit from that solution would be the ability to extract statistics about the whole class, like average grades, attendance etc